# how to dynamically change model query in controller in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, model, controller, laravel-5

This is my code

```
    $showid=3;
    $screenid='1';

    $seatdata=Screen1::all();

    $showtimedata=Showtime::where('showid',$showid)->get();
    $count =Showtime::where('showid',$showid)->count();
```

Now $showid and $screenid will be changing dynamically, there is no problem with showid it's working well, 
but whenever screen id changes then the model name written in the line below should change

```
    $seatdata=Screen1::all();
```

If say $screenid=2 then the code should become like

```
    $seatdata=Screen2::all();
```

If say $screenid=3 then the code should become like

```
   $seatdata=Screen3::all();
```

Note I have already created models Screen1, Screen2, & Screen3

I tried doing this but it didn't work

```
   $showid=3;
    $screenid='1';
    $screen='Screen'.$screenid;

    $seatdata=$screen::all();

    $showtimedata=Showtime::where('showid',$showid)->get();
    $count =Showtime::where('showid',$showid)->count();
```

This gives me error that

```
    FatalErrorException in SeatlayoutController.php line 27:Class 'Screen1' not found
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: `Screen1` probably lives in a namespace. Try including the namespace like this:`$screen = '\Namespace\Of\Screen'.$screenid;`. On a side note, are you sure this is the way you want to do it? I think you might need to rethink how your `Screen`s work.

Comment: Yes i want to do like this only. Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specify full namespace in your class, for example

```
$screen='App\Screen'.$screenid;
```

Comment: This worked                                                                                            $screenid=3;

        $screen='App\Screen'.$screenid;
     $seatdata=$screen::all();